# Selenium IDE Not Filling In Fields

Tags: selenium-ide

I am beginning to use Selenium-IDE, and I ran into an issue where the commands in my test case to type text into an input form doesn't work correctly. The id of the text field is correct, but no text shows up when the test runs. The commands in the test case were entered through the record-mode, so I am not sure if I should manually enter a command to do this instead. This works if I repeat the command, so I would have this twice:

```
type username   fakeuser@gmail.com
```

However, I do not want to put the same command twice for it to work, since it should work on the first command.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
type  id=username  fakeuser@gmail.com
```

Comment: I am not using selenium for this problem anymore, but thanks for the answer!